# Proper LINQ syntax to order Ienumerable based on value in Icollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following classes/tables:

```
public class Shift
{
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    //other irrelevant stuff...

    public virtual ICollection<ShiftMission> ShiftMission { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ShiftMission
 {
    public int ShiftMissionID { get; set; }        
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }

    //more irrelevant things
 }
```

In my index view of the shifts, I need the list to be sorted by DepartmentID, then by ShiftDate, and finally by the start time of the earliest/first mission in the collection of shift missions. It's sorting the shift missions that really has me stuck.

I've tried this but it tells me there is no column shiftdate and no column DepartmentID:

```
    var allShifts = _context.Shifts
            .Include(s => s.Department)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftMission).ThenInclude(sm => sm.Activity)
            .OrderBy(s => s.DepartmentID)
            .ThenBy(s => s.ShiftDate)
            .ThenBy(s => s.ShiftMission.OrderBy(sm => sm.StartTime).Select(sm => sm).FirstOrDefault());

        return View(allShifts.ToList());
```

I also tried selecting the shifts into a new group but that confused the hell out of me and caused even more exceptions and sorted DepartmentA below DepartmentB

```
 var allShifts = _context.Shifts
            .Include(s => s.Department)
            .Include(s => s.ShiftMission).ThenInclude(sm => sm.Activity)
            .GroupBy(s => s.DepartmentID)
            .Select(group => new {Shifts = group.OrderBy(x => x.ShiftDate).ThenBy(x => x.ShiftMission.OrderBy(sm => sm.StartTime).First())})
            .SelectMany(group => group.Shifts);
```

What's the proper way to achieve this? Every variation I make confuses me futher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort your Shifts by three values:

1. DepartmentId,
2. ShiftDate,
3. minimum StartTime of all StarTimes of ShiftMission items in Shift.ShiftMissions

To do this in one query that will be performed in one SQL query you can join your DbSet _context.Shifts and _context.ShiftMissions on equal shiftId.

The result of the join can be ordened the way you want:

```
var joinQuery = _context.Shifts.Join(_context.ShiftMissions, // join table Shifts and table ShiftMissions
    shift => shift.ShiftId,               // from the Shifts, take ShiftId
    shiftMission => shiftMission.ShiftId, // from the ShiftMisions taks ShiftId
    (shift, shiftMission) =>       // for all shifts and shiftMissions with equal shiftId take
    new {
        DepartmendId = shift.DepartmentId,
        ShiftDate = shift.ShiftDate,
        StartTime = shiftMission.StartTime,
        ShiftToSort = shift,
    });
```

Note that the query is not executed.

If you would execute the query you would see you would have created one table with records containing DepartmentId, ShiftDate, StartTime, and ShiftToSort that contains the original Shift where the three properties to sort on are extracted from.

Now if you sort them in the proper order, you'll get the items in the proper order:

```
var orderedQuery = joinQuery
    .OrderBy(item => item..DepartmentId)
    .ThenBy(item => item.ShiftDate)
    .ThenBy(item => item.StartTime)
```

This query will result in way too many ShiftToSort: the anonymous collection will have a ShiftToSort for every ShiftMission

You only want the distinct values of property ShiftToSort

```
var shiftToSortQuery = orderedQuery
    .Select(item => item.ShiftToSort)
    .Distinct();
```

Note that the query is still not executed!

```
var orderedList = finalQuery.ToList();
```

Of course you can write this in one statement:

```
var orderedList = _context.Shifts.Join(_context.ShiftMissions, // join table 
    ...
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

If you investigate the SQL statements that are performed when using an include you'll see that the include statement is translated into a SQL join.

```
var sortedQuery1 = _context.Shifts
    .OrderBy(shift => shift.DepartmentId)
    .ThenBy(shift => shift.ShiftDate);
```

the result must be ordered by the "minimum StartTime of all StartTimes of ShiftMission items in the shift). So for each element in sortedQuery1 you want to calculate the minimum startTime in the array of ShiftMissions. This is:

```
var sortedQuery2 = sortedQuery1
    .Orderby(itemSortedByDeparmentIdAndShiftDate =>
        // What value must be used to sort this item?
        // Answer: The minimum StartTime of all times in ShiftMissions
        // so for each item calculate the minimum Starttime:
        itemSortedByDepartmentIdAndShiftDate.ShiftMissions
            .Min(shiftMission => shiftMission.StartTime);
```

If you use your database profiler, you'll see that a similar join and sort is done, also completely in SQL, thus very efficiently

Comment: Wow... thank you for this thorough, detailed and extremely helpful explanation! I NEVER would have gotten here on my own. I had to read this at least five times and do a lot of debugging to get my head around it, but this cleared up so much confusion for me.

Comment: One question - when I do the final query in the first example you provided 
    orderedShifts.Select(s => s.ShiftToSort)
    .Distinct().ToList()

I see that the list gets built in order of ShiftID again and not according to the orderedShifts query. Why is that?

Comment: I was a bit short about the distinct part. The join flattens the shift and the shiftMissions. If shift X has 10 missions then the result will be 10 joined records, all with  shiftToSort == X, The three other fields are used to do the sorting. After the sort you'll see that in your sequence there are 10 items with the DepartmentId and ShitfDate of X, ordered by StartTime, each with the shiftToSort X. After the select you'll see 10 times the same X. The Distinct throws away the 9 X you don't need.

Comment: That part I understood, but I found that when I used Distinct() at the end of my query, before it was actually executed, Distinct() would re-order the Shifts by ShiftID and not by the previous OrderBy() instructions. I solved it by sending the query ToList() first. Then using Distinct() on the list itself instead of the query.  Thank you again for your help!